# Spring: Table already exists error! @DirtiesContext and EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder doesn work together?

Tags: java, spring, embedded-database

I got some errors while running a junit test class.

Here's my test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=TestApplicationContext.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class UserDaoTestDrive {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao dao;
```

This is my java class that I used for the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class TestApplicationContext {
...
    @Bean
    public DataSource embeddedDatabase() {

        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setName("embeddedDatabase").setType(HSQL).addScript("classpath:springbook/user/sqlservice/updatable/sqlRegistrySchema.sql").build();
    }
```

This is the error message.

```
Error creating bean with name 'embeddedDatabase' defined in class springbook.TestApplicationContext: 
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource springbook.TestApplicationContext.embeddedDatabase()] threw exception; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to execute database script;
...Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Table already exists
```

And I've got this weird [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwwTk.jpg), which fails every other test method.
I have 7 test methods and 1,3,5,7 always succeed and 2,4,6 always fail.

I have no idea why I get these errors because my test class worked well when I used an XML file for the context configuration

My XML file was like this.

```
<jdbc:embedded-database id="embeddedDatabase" type="HSQL">
  <jdbc:script location="classpath:springbook/user/sqlservice/updatable.sqlRegistrySchema.sql" />
<jdbc:embedded-database>
```

sqlRegistrySchema file

```
CREATE TABLE  SQLMAP(
KEY_ VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
SQL_ VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
```

Can anyone tell me why?

I guess the embedded db isn't closed as soon as every test method is finished.

Comment: Could you please post your updatable.sqlRegistrySchema.sql?

Comment: CREATE TABLE  SQLMAP(
 KEY_ VARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY,
 SQL_ VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS in your sql script. It looks like DB is hanging somewhere in the memory.